# Partition of nilpotent matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Find the partition p and the invertible matrix S for which $S^{-1}AS = N(p)$, where A is the following nilpotent matrix:

$$A = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -2 & 0 & -1 & 2 \\
1 & -3 & -1 & 0 & 3 \\
0 & 2 & 1 & -1 & -3 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & -1 & -2 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 2 \end{array} \right)$$

Can someone tell me what is meant by a partition of a nilpotent matrix? What exactly does $N(p)$ look like? And how do I find S?

Edit: Second matrix:

$$B = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-2 & 4 & -5 & 4 \\
4 & -2 & 4 & 4 \\
4 & -4 & 6 & 0 & \\
0 & -1 & 1 & -2 \end{array} \right)$$

Comment: The key here is to calculate rank$(A^k)$ for $k = 1,\dots,5$.

Comment: Have you considered this https://duckduckgo.com/?q=partition+of+a+matrix&t=keywordsearch&ia=qa ?

Comment: @MASL I don't see what's helpful about that link

Comment: @Omnomnomnom It's not clear what (s)he did so far to get an answer. The question "what is meant by..." can usually be addressed by googling for it. And indeed, that link provides many hits.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks for your comment. I have rank(A)=3, rank($A^2)=1$ and rank($A^3)=0$, what can I do with these ranks now? I still don't understand what the partition is? What kind of shape does N(p) have and what does N(p) even mean?

Comment: @MASL lots of hits, none of which clearly answers the question

Comment: @Omnomnomnom It's pointless to argue about this. I'm not saying anything beyond the most basic point in SO: show some work done. I think you understood me wrong here.

Comment: @MASL I understand what you're getting at, but I think it's clear when you *look at what comes up* in the search that it's not that easy to find out what is meant by the "partition of a nilpotent matrix".

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Just to settle a truce here: I could have made a more direct comment instead of being somewhat ironic. True. That's *another* legit comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your calculations, we have rank$(A) = 3$, rank$(A)^2 = 1$, and $A^3 = 0$.  $A$ is a $5\times 5$ matrix.

Let $J$ denote the Jordan normal form of $A$, We find, then, that $J$ has $5 - 3 = 2$ $0$-blocks of size at least $1$, $3 - 1 = 2$ $0$-blocks of size at least $2$, and $1 - 0 = 1$ block of size at least $3$.  Conclude that $J$ has the form
$$
J = \pmatrix{0&1\\&0\\&&0&1\\&&&0&1\\&&&&0}
$$
Up to a permutation of the blocks. I suppose, then, that $p = (3,2)$. In general, your partition should be the sizes of the blocks in descending order.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late comment, but I'm still not sure how you came up with (3,2) from the numbers (2,2,1), can you explain that? Maybe to make this clearer and for me to not have to open another question. I have another exercise, where I'm given a nilpotent matrix and I have to calculate the corresponding partition of 4, where the ranks are: rank(A)=3, rank(A^2)=2,rank(A^3)=2, rank(A^4)=2. Do you have any idea what the partition to 4 is supposed to look like in this case?

Comment: That other matrix is not nilpotent. As for $2,2,1$, the key is how you interpret those numbers.  There are $2$ blocks of size at least $1$, $2$ blocks of size at least $2$, and $1$ block of size at least $3$, with no additional blocks.  Because $A^3 = 0$, we actually also know that every block is size $3$ or smaller.  With all of that information, it's easy to deduce that there is one block of size $3$, and one of size $2$.

Comment: I can tell you for that other matrix that the algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda = 0$ is $2$, and that there is one size-$2$ Jordan block associated with $0$.  I can't tell what the other eigenvalues are from that information alone.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I really appreciate it. I've edited the question to post the second matrix. How do you know that this matrix is not nilpotent? The question says that it is nilpotent. Can you now comment on the partition part of the second matrix? Also do you have a good reference that focuses on the computational part of the Jordan form, i.e. coming up with the jordan basis?

Comment: Edit2: Seems as if the second matrix is wrong. If you change the 4,4 element in the matrix from -2 to 2, you get A^2=0. Then the partition is clear (2,2). Thanks again for your help.

Comment: How did you decide what the partition is?  If we indeed have $B^2 = 0$, then I would agree.

Comment: I have found a statement in Carl D. Meyers textbook that says that the number of i x i Jordan blocks is equal to $v_i = r_{i-1}-2r_i+r_{i+1}$, where $r_i = rank(L^i)$. However the statement wasn't proved and I don't really understand the intuition behind it. The Jordan form is still new to me and I'm kind of struggling with the reference text that I have, do you know any textbook that nicely teaches the Jordan form?

Comment: @eager2learn I used Horn and Johnson. You might also want to try Friedberg, Insel, Spense.